# How to Iterate through Ajax data response

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, loops

for my code, I the following response JSON response

```
{
"command": "SELECT",
"rowCount": 2,
"oid": null,
"rows": [
    {
        "name": "Life Insurance Silver",
        "product__c": "01t2o000007pd3MAAQ"
    },
    {
        "name": "Life Insurance Gold",
        "product__c": "01t2o000007pdqpAAA"
    }
],
```

How do I iterate through this array to display the name and the product__c in my table using Ajax?
At moment my call is showing undefined for both name and product

```
cols += '<td> ' + row.name + '</td>';
cols += '<td> ' + row.product__c + '</td>';
```

here is the Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                url: event.target.action,
                method: event.target.method,
                
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('#### sucessful data retrieve string' + JSON.stringify(data));

                     $.each(data.rows, function(row) {
                        console.log('#### ROWS ' + row);

                        var newRow = $("<tr>");
                            var cols = "";
                           
                            var contractName = $("#name").val();
                            var productName = $("#product__c").val();
                            cols += '<td> ' + row.name + '</td>';
                            cols += '<td> ' + row.product__c + '</td>';
                            newRow.append(cols);
                            $("#panel tbody").append(newRow);
                     });

                    $("#messageContract").text("Success!");
                    $("#messageC").show();
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    errorMessage.text(err.responseJSON.error);
                    error.show();
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct the $.each loop the first parameter to the callback function in $.each is the index and the second one is each iterated item.

```js
$.each(data.rows, function(index,row) {
                        console.log('#### ROWS ' + row);

                        var newRow = $("<tr>");
                            var cols = "";
                           
                            var contractName = $("#name").val();
                            var productName = $("#product__c").val();
                            cols += '<td> ' + row.name + '</td>';
                            cols += '<td> ' + row.product__c + '</td>';
                            newRow.append(cols);
                            $("#panel tbody").append(newRow);
                     });
```